# get all repo commits using pygit2 with svn repos

Tags: git, python-2.7, svn, version-control, pygit2

Now i'm using git svn for cloning repos, when i want to get all their commits and store whem to the db.

For getting all the commits i use `pygit2.Repository` but i see that i receive only commits from '/trunk/' branch.

If i use `git branch -a` in terminal i can see all branches:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/test-1
  remotes/origin/test-1@468
  remotes/origin/trunk
```

And when i do `git log remotes/origin/test-1` i see result with proper commits.

But when i try to receive all commits from repo using `pygit2.Repository` i receive commits only from trunk, not from other branches - can you advise me a way to get commits from branches too? Maybe i should not use pygit2 but use some other python module?

using repo.listall_branches(2) i see what pygit2 see this branches:

```
['origin/test-1', 'origin/trunk', 'origin/test-1@468']
```

but when i try to do `repo.lookup_branch('origin/test-1')` or `repo.lookup_branch('remote/origin/test-1')` i receive None instead of `pygit2.Branch` objects

and when i do

```
head = repo.lookup_branch('master').get_object()
for native_commit in repo.walk(head.hex):
    print(i)
```

i receive only commits from `trunk`. 
Please, tell me a proper way to receive all commits from all branches not only commits from `trunk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its documentation at http://www.pygit2.org/references.html#branches, `repo.branches` should give you all branches, local *and* remote ones.

Comment: I use previous version of pygit2 it doesn't have repo.branches yet. But i figure out how to get all commits: you need to pass branch_type like this - using this code i receive all needed commits heads head = repo.lookup_branch('origin/test-1', 2).get_object() and when i do repo.walk(head.hex) for all branches